In logistic mixed model the estimate changes but it does not for a gaussian
Comparing 2 logistic models:
result~1 

and
result~1|randomeffect

The estimate (i.e. the log(odds) of the proportion) changes between the two models & I'm struggling to explain this.
When I experiment on a gaussian model with mock data, the only way of getting the mean, to shift, is to have unequal number of observations in the groups for the random effect (and I understand why that would happen).
However, when working in logistic/binary, even if I have an equal number of observations per group in the random effect, I get a change in the estimate (for the log odds of the proportion).
I'd like to be able to explain this to a lay audience because otherwise it undermines the credibility of moving from the base model to the mixed model.
Can anyone advise?

I edited your question to make it clearer. If I made it less clear, you can change it back.

I believe the crux is that for a non-identity GLMM the marginal (population-averaged) model is not the same as the conditional model with random effects set to zero, whereas under an identity link that equivalence holds. The reason is that the link is non-linear, so a shift in prediction produced by a change in a random effect parameter isn't either.

Dimitris Rizopoulos has a lot of great material & discussion on this, see e.g. here, here, and check out his lecture notes (slide 318 & on) too.

@PeterFlom yes you've made it clearer.

@PBulls
I agree: I think that is the crux (non-linear Vs linear link).
With simulations, almost always the predicted proportion is shifted in the direction AWAY from 50% by the inclusion of a random effect which I think is in keeping with  it being the non-linear link.
My problem is
a) should I PREFER the proportion that is estimated when the group effect is included (its inclusion is supported by AIC comparison so I think so);
b) How do I explain this shift to a lay audience.
I'm still getting to grips with Dimitris' explanations.

It's not so much preference; it would almost invariably be less correct not to include hierarchical effects if they exist (violation of i.i.d. otherwise). However, the interpretation of a non-identity GLMM's coefficients is not that of a GLM's: the former are not marginal out of the box unlike non-mixed or identity-linked mixed models. Perhaps an alternative solution is to use GEE, which gives you marginal (and only marginal) estimates? Otherwise you should probably marginalize your GLMM's coefficients which should give point estimates closer to the GLM while accounting for clustering.

Yes, I agree - it would not be correct not to include the hierarchical effect.
I will look into your recommendations of marginal estimates via GEE.
thank you.
